# Sorting elements by column in R

Tags: r

I have a simple code for matrix

```
ind1=which(macierz==1,arr.ind = TRUE)
```

fragment of theresult is

```
> ind1
                row col
TCGA.CH.5737.01  53   1
TCGA.CH.5791.01  66   1
P03.1334.Tumor  322   1
P04.1790.Tumor  327   1
CPCG0340.F1     425   1
TCGA.CH.5737.01  53   2
TCGA.CH.5791.01  66   2
P03.1334.Tumor  322   2
P04.1790.Tumor  327   2
CPCG0340.F1     425   2
```

I would like to sort it by first column alphabetical. How can I do this in R?

Comment: It looks as if the first column is rownames, so you probably need something like `ind1 <- ind1[order(rownames(ind1))]`

Comment: As a side note. According to documentation "A data frame has (by definition) a vector of row names which has length the number of rows in the data frame, and contains neither missing nor duplicated values" so those could not be rownames (Source: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/row.names.html). Someone with more knowledge of the internal working of R may shed some light on the subject.

Comment: `ind1[order(rownames(ind1))]`    returns only vector of elements in row and i would like to have whole matrix sorted by first column.

Comment: Sorry - it needs an extra comma, as `ind1` is a matrix... try `ind1[order(rownames(ind1)),]`

Comment: do a dput on your dataframe  and paste the outcome on the quesiton. people than can help you out. e.g `dput(ind1)` Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if `ind1` is a matrix and the first column is the rownames, so you probably need something like `ind1 <- ind1[order(rownames(ind1)),]`

Answer (score 0):

You need (assuming your first column is called "label" and those are not rownames)

```
 ind1[order(ind1$label),]
```

`order()` return a list of row indexes after sorting alphabetically the data frame. Just to make the example reproducible I created your data frame so

```
ind1 <- data.frame ( label = c("TCGA.CH.5737.01", "TCGA.CH.5791.01", 
"P03.1334.Tumor","P04.1790.Tumor", "CPCG0340.F1" , "TCGA.CH.5737.01", 
"TCGA.CH.5791.01","P03.1334.Tumor", "P04.1790.Tumor", "CPCG0340.F1"),
                 row = c(53,66,322,327,425,53,66,322,327,425), col = 
                 c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

and the output is

```
> ind1[order(ind1$label),]
             label row col
5      CPCG0340.F1 425   1
10     CPCG0340.F1 425   2
3   P03.1334.Tumor 322   1
8   P03.1334.Tumor 322   2
4   P04.1790.Tumor 327   1
9   P04.1790.Tumor 327   2
1  TCGA.CH.5737.01  53   1
6  TCGA.CH.5737.01  53   2
2  TCGA.CH.5791.01  66   1
7  TCGA.CH.5791.01  66   2
```

Hope that helps.

Regards, Umberto

Comment: After using, I have an error Error in `ind1$label : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`, how to avoid it?

Comment: Reason is that probably your data frame is different. To help you we should see it. Could you post an example (maybe with less data)? Then we can help you better.

Comment: Sample data:

`set.seed(2)
n <- 10
mtx <- array(NA, dim = c(n, n))
dimnames(mtx) <- list(letters[1:n], LETTERS[1:n])
mtx[sample(n*n, size = 4)] <- paste0("x",1:4)
mtx
cos=which(mtx>1,arr.ind = TRUE)`
 this is similar example to mine.

Comment: I'm sorry, i changed it a bit now, `cos=which(mtx>1,arr.ind = TRUE)`